# Is there a way to use Gruntjs without running into file path issues on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, gruntjs

I started "using" Grunt.js yesterday, it seems to nest extensively deep folder structures in my projects, that look something like this:

> assets\bootstrap\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\brace-expansion\node_modules\balanced-match\Makefile

This still is a realtively short path, but there are loads of paths generated which my PC (running Windows 7) simply **can't handle**. I see this a well known issue as you can read in this Github issue of Node.js from 2014:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6960#issuecomment-46704998

However the issue still isn't fixed and a lot of people seem to be mad about it.
I wonder if I should get my head around Grunt at all because I didn't see a solid solution to get this working for me so far.

Even if I started using Mac (assumed Grunt.js works fine on mac), from my point of view Grunt seems to be a bad option if you want to be able to collaborate with people using windows.

**Is there an easy way to use Gruntjs without running into file path issues on Windows?**

*update: This is what GIT BASH throws at me when I am trying to track my files using `git add .`

> warning: unable to access 'node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/node_modules/bin-v                                                                                                                                                                                               ersion-check/node_modules/bin-version/node_modules/find-versions/node_modules/me                                                                                                                                                                                               ow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/find-up/node_modules/pinkie-promise/nod                                                                                                                                                                                               e_modules/pinkie/.gitignore': Filename too long

Comment: I'm using Grunt on Win7 without issues. I do use Cygwin though (not that that matters), and have my projects in `D:\code\`. Windows is notorious for it's limitations path lengths.

Comment: I used NPM to install the grunt plugins. Did you also use that?

Comment: Yes indeed. Where's your code located? If the base path is pretty deep you could move it to `C:\myproject` or something. You could also try installing grunt and grunt modules globally (they'll end up in your homedir).

Comment: My code is located in subfolders like xampp/htdocs/project/wp-content/themes/themename 
but I had another project which i took over from another developer and when I tried copying the folders onto my hard disk, even putting everything directly under c:/ didn't make enough space for the nested folders' paths. So if anything, this gives you some more space. But the concept doesn't seem reliable to me. Its these endless node_modules nested into eachother... I wonder if Mac handles it flawless..

Comment: Pretty much anything other than Windows will handle much deeper paths.
However you are better off not working in a wp theme directory, but have your theme project someplace else, and deploy the generated theme files (without the node_modules) either directly to the wp theme directory, or use the wp update mechanism and a private repository.

Comment: I want to work with Git as a Versioncontrol system and I develop locally. So lets say I put my theme project into C:\code and deploy it locally to xampp/htdocs/project. What files would you put under C:/code then? What is the wp update mechanism? Which should be my repository, I guess the folder under xampp/htdocs? So much to learn these days.. it's a bit confusing

Comment: Sorry to have confused you. You move all of the files in `wp-content/themes/mytheme/` to, for example, `c:/code/mytheme/`. The `mytheme` in wp is then empty. You then run Grunt in `c:\code\mytheme`, which generates the files (css from less, uglified js from js etc..). Then copy only the needed files back to the `wp-content/themes/mytheme` directory: pretty much everything except `Gruntfile.js`, `package.json`, `node_modules/`.
Your repository would be in `c:/code/mytheme`, containing just your theme. The WP update is just the plugin/theme updates; better skip that for now :-)

Comment: Thanks for your support by the way!
Following your suggestion that means the repository is not taking care of anything else but the theme folder, can I still use the version control as a backup then? Is it only the plugins and database that is missing then?
My head is kind of smoking... I will continue tommorow

Comment: You're welcome - AFAIK SO frowns upon chats in comments so we could continue in a separate chat tomorrow or so. And yes, you can keep the entire site in version control of course; you're just extracting a re-usable component (a theme, plugin, ...) into a separate project. I do understand the benefit of keeping the entire site in Git - I do that too, for backups and quick reverting. The answer to your original question then is: No, there is no easy way.. besides perhaps [`npm install -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally)

Comment: It would be awesome if we could have a chat about this. However it says my reputation on SO is too low to chat... can't send a private message either appearently

Comment: I'm not getting a chat option here either. I would suggest though, to check the `npm install -g` link in my previous comment; this would install node modules globally (perhaps in 'C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node_modules' or in your home directory), and might bypass the path-depth problem.

Comment: I installed it in a really short path but it's still not working. What about putting all the grunt files under node_modules in gitignore?
Do you install grunt locally in the project folder for wordpress projects?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting an error? Could you update the question with your commandline and the error output? As for gitignore, that just tells git to not consider the files/directories listed in there for version control. Are you having trouble checking out the project, npm installing it, or running grunt?

Comment: updated it. And there are tons of those error messages. All related to node_modules folderpaths

Comment: Aha. Yes, update .gitignore to exclude node_modules; you don't want those dependencies in your repository, just the package.json and Gruntfile.js (and your source files). Anyone who checks out the project can/must run npm install.

Comment: okay so I now have a repo with only the files under wp-content/themes/mytheme/
Do you have a second repo for the whole project? What is your workflow with git and wordpress? is there maybe a slack team you are in I could join?

Comment: No, I don't have a slack team.. There's also chat.stackoverflow.com but idk what reputation you would need.. I'll do a write-up in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use [GULP](http://gulpjs.com/) Or move your project to root directory of your drive, I am not sure if this is a grunt specific issue or rather a node specific issue